# Shoretel ST1D Switch not accepting assigned IP

Tags: switch, dhcp, ip-address

After configuring a Shortel ST1D switch, I connected the LAN1 Port from Shoretel ST1D to my Cisco 4507R switch. I attempted to ping the IP that I set specifically on the ST1D switch and I wasn't able to reach that IP.

Troubleshooting:

-I ran a `show mac address-table | i` on the port that I plugged into and found the mac address.

-I took that and ran a `show arp | i *mac address*` and found that the new Shoretel ST1D switch registered with a completely different IP assigned by DHCP.

-I found out right after that we have a DHCP server sitting behind that switch which would hand out IP's to whatever device connects to that switch.

My question is, why would DHCP assign an IP even though I specifically directed the Shoretel switch to assign that particular IP to itself? Why would DHCP take priority over a static IP address?

--*A side note, I checked to make sure the static IP that is on the shoretel switch configuration was not taken by any other device prior to plugging into the Cisco 4507R switch.*--

Here is the Shoretel switch configuration if it helps:

```
Current system configuration:
 DHCP                    = enabled
 FTP user name           = anonymous
 FTP password            = tskl
 Ethernet address        = 00:10:49:X:X:X -omitted-
 Service IP address      = 192.168.31.6
 IP subnet mask          = 255.255.255.0
 Server IP address       = 0.0.0.0
 Controlling Server IP address = 0.0.0.0
 Gateway IP address      = 192.168.31.1
 Image Server address    =
 DNS IP address          = 192.168.20.240  192.168.32.215
 Time server IP address  = 0.shor.pool.ntp.org 1.shor.po
 Ethernet link set       = no link
 Ethernet link requested = automatic
 Domain name             =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the very first line of the configuration, you have DHCP enabled, so the switch will configure itself via DHCP:

```
Current system configuration:
 DHCP                    = enabled
```

If you want to statically assign the switch address, then you should disable DHCP on the switch.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Sometimes the most obvious things are staring right at you. lol

Comment: That happens to all of us. Fortunately, you provided enough information to be able to see the problem.